# how to highlight a table cell onClick with unique colors in each cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

In the fiddle below, you can click on any of the cells and they will change colors to those in td.highlighted in the CSS. I want the highlighted color to be assigned inline instead and unique to each element.

https://jsfiddle.net/rvxnmz8r/7

this is the line that generates the style for each table element, and I think the main problem is that I am dumb with CSS. Thanks for any help.

```
var hstyle = 'style="td.highlighted {background-color: ' + '#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6)  + '; color: black;}"';
```

update: the cells need to remain toggle-able between the default and custom highlighted colors.

Comment: You do not need `td.highlighted `{` in your style setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using inline style combined with external CSS, the external need `!important` to override the inline style.

*As a side note, using `!important` impact the usability of styling in a more difficult way to reuse, though, in your case, create 60 classes to toggle, I found more bad, hence the use of `!important`*

Change your script to

```
var hstyle = 'style="background-color: ' + '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6) + '; color: black;"';`
```

And your CSS to

```
td.highlighted {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

Stack snippet

```js
var elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var transtable = [elements, elements, elements, elements, elements, elements];

var output = [];
output.push('<table id="taxatable">');
for (var row = 0; row < transtable[0].length; row++) {
  output.push('<tr>');
  for (var col = 0; col < transtable.length; col++) {
    var hclass = 'class="highlighted"';
    var hstyle = 'style="background-color: ' + '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6) + '; color: black;"';
    output.push(
      '<td ' + hclass + ' ' + hstyle + '>' + escape(transtable[col][row]) + '</td>'
    );
  }
  output.push('</tr>');
}
output.push('</table>');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output.join('');

var tbl = document.getElementById("taxatable");
if (tbl != null) {
  for (var trow = 0; trow < tbl.rows.length; trow++) {
    for (var tcol = 0; tcol < tbl.rows[trow].cells.length; tcol++) {
      tbl.rows[trow].cells[tcol].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("highlighted");
      };

      //console.log(tbl.rows[trow].cells[tcol]);

    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

td.highlighted {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: that did it, brilliant. never heard of !important before!

Comment: Sorry I downvoted, but simply saying 'use !important' without explaining how this has great impact on the reusability of your code is a no go in my book.

Comment: @Phortuin Thanks for commenting your down vote. Well, you do as you wish, but since the OP combine an inline style with an external class, and to create 60 classes to hold 60 unique colors would be really a bad idea, the `!important` is a must, I will make a note though, about its impact

Comment: @LGSon You’re absolutely right, I should have tested first. I removed the down vote

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

I see what you’re trying to do, but your solution is mixing two things together: inline styles and CSS rules. You can only use `style=""` on an element to set styling directly on that element, which overrides the rules from your stylesheet. If you want to toggle the `highlight` class on and off you could do something like this (using jQuery):

```
$("td").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
});
```

Also, it needs the `!important` modifier in the `highlighted` class, as @LGSon explains above.

In combination with my answer below (removing `td.highlighted` in the inline style), this should probably result in what you are looking for.

---

**Old answer**

If you use inline styles, you are styling directly on the HTML element and you won’t need to define a CSS selector. Instead of

```
var hstyle = 'style="td.highlighted {background-color...
```

you can simply write:

```
var hstyle = 'background-color...'
```

So, your code becomes:

```
var hstyle = 'style="background-color: ' + '#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6)  + '; color: black;"';
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need it to also go back to being unhighlighted when you click again... it should remain toggleable

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Remove the td.highlighted like so

```
var hstyle = 'style="background-color: ' + '#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6)  + '; color: black;"';
```